# what's the difference between performance metrics and evaluation metrics?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-analysis

what's the difference between performance metrics and evaluation metrics in evaluating a classifier?
I have searched and i am not sure if they are different.

Comment: they aren't. up to some rare different use cases (it always happens from time to time) these are exact same things

Comment: okay, thanks..i get now

Answer (score 0):

"Performance metrics" and "evaluation metrics" mean the same thing. They can be used interchangeably.